# Find all spanning tree in a given graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm, trees

Is there a way I can generate all the spanning tree in the following graph:

[image]

Also, is there a way to insert the adjacency matrix, then I get an output of all possible spanning trees?

The adjacency matrix
$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written the adjacency matrix for this? Please, share such things with us so that we may help to better answer your question?

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you, I add the adjacency matrix, but I don't know where to start to final *all* the possible spanning tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
am = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}};

g0 = UndirectedGraph[SimpleGraph @ AdjacencyGraph @ am, 
  VertexCoordinates -> Reverse @ CirclePoints[{1, Pi}, 6], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
trees = Select[TreeGraphQ[Graph@#] &] @ Select[VertexCount @ # == 6 &]@ 
  Subsets[EdgeList[g0], {5}];

Length @ trees
```

> ```
> 32
> ```

This matches what we should expect from [Kirchhoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem):

```
Det[KirchhoffMatrix[g0][[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]]
```

> ```
> 32
> ```

We can also get the same number using `IGSpanningTreeCount` from `IGraphM` package:

```
<< IGraphM`
IGSpanningTreeCount[g0]
```

> ```
> 32
> ```

These 32 trees fall into three isomorphic groups:

```
Length /@ Gather[Graph /@ trees, IsomorphicGraphQ]
```

> ```
> {10, 16, 6}
> ```

```
Graph[#, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexStyle -> White,
    GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", 
    VertexShapeFunction -> (Disk[#, Offset[7]] &), 
    AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ trees // Multicolumn[#, 6] &
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[g0, #, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ trees // 
 Multicolumn[#, 6, Appearance -> "Horizontal"] &
```

[image]

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't think your answer could be improved.  But then you added Kirchhoff's Theorem!  Awesome!

Comment: Thank you @Adam and Mubarak for the kind words.

Answer (score 3):

Does the following what you want? First we create the graph from the adjacency matrix:

```
a = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
agr = AdjacencyGraph[a]
```

[image]

Then we create the spanning trees:

```
FindSpanningTree[{agr, #}, VertexLabels -> "Name"] & /@ Range[6]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But it does not generate all of them. But @Kglr solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I may as well add a way to construct the graph

```
g=Graph[Join[#\[UndirectedEdge]#+1&/@Range@5,{1\[UndirectedEdge]6,
3\[UndirectedEdge]5,4\[UndirectedEdge]6}]]
```

---

In general Mathematica has no good way to do this.  Here's a naive method.

Trees on $n$ vertices have $n-1$ edges.  For every length $n-1$ tuple of edges, is it a tree?

```
trees=Select[Tuples[EdgeList@g,{VertexCount@g-1}],TreeGraphQ@Graph@#&]
```

For the `g` in question, <s>I find 3840 unique trees.</s>  Of course `Subsets` is appropriate as opposed to `Tuples`, which causes this confusion. Here's a neat way to find all isomorphic trees:

```
Module[{l={}},For[i=1,i<=Length@trees,++i,
    If[And@@Table[Not@IsomorphicGraphQ[Graph@e,Graph@trees[[i]]],{e,l}],
    AppendTo[l,trees[[i]]]
]];l]
```

which produces 3 unique-up-to-isomorphism trees.